# nodeenv hangs when setting up a new environment

Tags: node.js

I tried using `nodeenv` in the following way:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python2.7 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip2.7 install nodeenv
(venv) $ nodeenv --node=0.12.2 nenv
```

But it hangs on:

```
 * Install node (0.12.2)..
```

I am not sure how to investigate this issue. Thoughts? Do I need to install Node before all that (currently, `$ node \ -sh: node: command not found`)? I was under the impression that the correct version of Node would be installed by `nodeenv`.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not hanged, but just slow.  `nodeenv` runs a C++ compiler (presumably to compile v8).  For that reason, creating a nodeenv environment takes several minutes on my computer.  To avoid that you can use the `--prebuilt` switch to download a prebuilt node.js rather than compiling from source:

```
nodeenv --prebuilt nenv
```

If you do opt to compile, you can watch it do its work by running nodeenv and then, while that's still going, running a command like this:

```
watch 'ps auxfwww | grep -A4 make'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use the Will Farrington's `nodenv` program.

It is a simply shell script that allow you to setup node.js in its multiples versions, even io.js versions.

To install the latest stable release:

```
git clone -b v0.3.4 https://github.com/wfarr/nodenv.git ~/.nodenv
```

Then add the following to your shell config at the end:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.nodenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(nodenv init -)"
```

For usage and more information read the Readme file at the repo: https://github.com/wfarr/nodenv

Answer (score 0):

> It actually not hang, its speed issue as answered, by using **nodeenv
>   --verbose nenv** we can see what is processing. When we use **nodeenv nenv** it looks like it hang but in background process is running but its slow, we can see
>   this py using **--verbose**.
>
> To create environment can using prebuilt node.js, this will be fast:

```
  nodeenv --prebuilt nenv
```

**> Note:** Sometime when we run nodeenv nenv, it creates env folder but not

> bin inside if we keyinterrupt in between.So delete that nenv and then
>   run nodeenv --prebuilt nenv.
>
> To Activate environment:

```
source nenv/bin/activate
```

> or

```
. nenv/bin/activate
```

> To deactivate:

```
deactivate_node
```